# How to use the last branch build status in pull requests at Azure DevOps?

Tags: build, azure-devops, pull-request

I created a new build pipeline for my latest project at Azure DevOps Server 2019. I use the provided Git repository with branch policies to protect `master` and `develop` from changes without pull request.

Each pull request requires a successful build.Unfortunately, Azure DevOps Server always creates a new build for each pull request (*highlighted red in the image below*).

I don’t need that build. The last build status of the assigned branch is enough.Is there any way to disable the pull request build and use the last branch status instead?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the pull request build to turned off? You can deselect it from the triggers under the build as described under the PR Triggers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the new build is required, because it should verify whether the build works fine after migrating the code from source branch to target branch (master/develop).

Regarding the build for assigned branch, it just verifies the current branch instead of the migrated code. (maybe there are some bugs/issues after migrating code)

Comment: Make sense. On other systems I used `--ff-only` as pull request merge strategy, thanks.